# Add attribute/variable to ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-view

I want to set an `ImageView` and want to save a special attribute to it.
So I set an `ImageView` with

```
FrameLayout root1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(root);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seite2);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 8);
root1.addView(view, params);
view.bringToFront();
view.setX(paramsinx);
view.setY(paramsiny);
```

Now I want to save an attribute to each view. For example by creating I set up the attribute name=tree for every new view.
Later, I want to edit this to for example name=plant or name=blueberry and get the name out of the image to identify it or make some if conditions.

I tried tags but the problem was it is meant for objects and not names or ids.

Edit Output:

```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                   Process: com.example.appdesp_seminarsapp_entwicklung20172018, PID: 5319
>                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object
> android.widget.ImageView.getTag()' on a null object reference
>                       at com.example.appdesp_seminarsapp_entwicklung20172018.Klassisch.angemalt(Klassisch.java:313)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
> Application terminated.
```

Only making the Toast and saying "hi" works. With gettag this error occures.

```
String test = (String) img1.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(Klassisch.this, "hi"+test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

(I created an imageview img1)
Edit2: Thanks for inserting code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You looked on the right way, tags is what you need!

Set your name with `setTag` method:

```
String defaultName = "tree";
view.setTag(defaultName);
...
view.setTag("plant");
```

And when you need it, just get tag value and cast it to `String`

```
String name = (String) view.getTag();
```

Comment: Mhh I tried that and he said he found an object (the tag) and the string is required by the first part.

Comment: public void feldSetzengerade(float paramsinx, float paramsiny, final ImageView view) {

        FrameLayout root1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(root);

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seite);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(8, 50);
        root1.addView(view, params);
        view.setTag("seite");
        view.bringToFront();
        view.setX(paramsinx);
        view.setY(paramsiny);

I created a view with name img1 and some params, also declared on top.

Comment: Now tried to get the tag by:  public void angemalt(View view){

        String test = (String) img1.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(Klassisch.this, "hi"+test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
(I use a Button to try it, hi alone works, with the tag the app crashes)

Comment: it looks like `img1`is null, where do you instantiate it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in a test project.

This works, my problem was:
I used the global variable img1 and img1.getTag. I set up the img1 in the onCreate with: test(50,100,img1) and I declared img1 on top.
Instead I'm now using view.getTag() and pass the view by the parameter.

2.Solution: img1 in onCreate is not the same with img1 on top.

```
package com.example.test;import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;import android.os.Bundle;import android.view.View;import android.widget.FrameLayout;import android.widget.ImageView;import android.widget.Toast;public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {ImageView img1;@Overrideprotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this); // correct: img1=new ImageView(this) because already defined on top 
    test(50,100,img1);
    getTag(img1);
}

public void test(int paramsinx, int paramsiny, View view) {
    String name= "Marc";
    FrameLayout root1 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(50, 8);
    root1.addView(view, params);
    view.bringToFront();
    view.setX(paramsinx);
    view.setY(paramsiny);
    view.setTag(name);


}
public void getTag(View view) {
    String test = (String) view.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi"+test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//or directly: public void getTag() {
String test = (String) img1.getTag();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hi"+test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```